# Gradle : how to use Maven project source as dependency

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I use Intellij to develop a gradle Java project. For the moment I use :

```
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'com.health.project:1.0"
  }
}

...
implementation 'com.health.project:common'
```

in my gradle to retrieve this dependency.

But now I need to **modify** the source code of this project `com.health.project`, so I want to know how I can import it in intellij and tells intellij to use the imported project as dependency ?

Comment: in Intellij  you should add it as a module of your current project (project explorer window > new > module)
Choose the "Gradle" type.

Comment: Currently such setup is not supported for Gradle projects. There is however a hidden option that you may try to set which **may** help: `external.system.substitute.library.dependencies = true` via Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart. Note: the Maven pom.xml module coordinates must be same as you specify in Gradle and this Maven module must be added to the same IDE project.